# Why am I getting RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support with detectron2?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, detectron

I am trying to run the code from:
https://github.com/cvlab-stonybrook/ContactHands on Windows 10.

It uses detectron2 and pytorch with CUDA. I installed CUDA 11.6, pytorch 1.12.0 (with `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.6 -c pytorch -c conda-forge`), detectron 0.1.1, and python 3.7.13.

This is my environment from `python -m detectron2.utils.collect_env`:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.platform              win32
Python                    3.7.13 (default, Mar 28 2022, 08:03:21) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
numpy                     1.21.6
detectron2                0.1.1 @c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2
detectron2 compiler       MSVC 191627048
detectron2 CUDA compiler  not available
detectron2 arch flags     c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2\_C.cp37-win_amd64.pyd; cannot find cuobjdump
DETECTRON2_ENV_MODULE     <not set>
PyTorch                   1.12.0 @C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torch
PyTorch debug build       False
CUDA available            True
GPU 0                     NVIDIA GeForce MX250
CUDA_HOME                 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6
NVCC                      Not Available
Pillow                    9.2.0
torchvision               0.13.0 @C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torchvision
torchvision arch flags    C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torchvision\_C.pyd; cannot find cuobjdump
cv2                       4.5.5
------------------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PyTorch built with:
  - C++ Version: 199711
  - MSVC 192829337
  - Intel(R) Math Kernel Library Version 2020.0.2 Product Build 20200624 for Intel(R) 64 architecture applications
  - Intel(R) MKL-DNN v2.6.0 (Git Hash 52b5f107dd9cf10910aaa19cb47f3abf9b349815)
  - OpenMP 2019
  - LAPACK is enabled (usually provided by MKL)
  - CPU capability usage: AVX2
  - CUDA Runtime 11.6
  - NVCC architecture flags: -gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-gencode;arch=compute_70,code=sm_70;-gencode;arch=compute_75,code=sm_75;-gencode;arch=compute_80,code=sm_80;-gencode;arch=compute_86,code=sm_86;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=compute_37
  - CuDNN 8.3.2  (built against CUDA 11.5)
  - Magma 2.5.4
  - Build settings: BLAS_INFO=mkl, BUILD_TYPE=Release, CUDA_VERSION=11.6, CUDNN_VERSION=8.3.2, CXX_COMPILER=C:/cb/pytorch_1000000000000/work/tmp_bin/sccache-cl.exe, CXX_FLAGS=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /w /bigobj -DUSE_PTHREADPOOL -openmp:experimental -IC:/cb/pytorch_1000000000000/work/mkl/include -DNDEBUG -DUSE_KINETO -DLIBKINETO_NOCUPTI -DUSE_FBGEMM -DUSE_XNNPACK -DSYMBOLICATE_MOBILE_DEBUG_HANDLE -DEDGE_PROFILER_USE_KINETO, LAPACK_INFO=mkl, PERF_WITH_AVX=1, PERF_WITH_AVX2=1, PERF_WITH_AVX512=1, TORCH_VERSION=1.12.0, USE_CUDA=ON, USE_CUDNN=ON, USE_EXCEPTION_PTR=1, USE_GFLAGS=OFF, USE_GLOG=OFF, USE_MKL=ON, USE_MKLDNN=OFF, USE_MPI=OFF, USE_NCCL=OFF, USE_NNPACK=OFF, USE_OPENMP=ON, USE_ROCM=OFF,
```

and when I run

```
python -c "import torch; from torch.utils.cpp_extension import CUDA_HOME; print(torch.cuda.is_available(), CUDA_HOME)"
```

I get

```
True C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.6
```

However, when I run the training command

```
python train_net.py --first-config-file configs/ContactHands.yaml
```

I get the error

```
RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support
```

This is the full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train_net.py", line 281, in <module>
    args=(args,),
  File "c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2\engine\launch.py", line 52, in launch
    main_func(*args)
  File "train_net.py", line 269, in main
    do_train(cfg1, model1, model2, resume=args.resume)
  File "train_net.py", line 171, in do_train
    second_stream_outputs = inference_second_stream(model2, data, height, width)
  File "train_net.py", line 60, in inference_second_stream
    outputs = model(im)
  File "C:\detectron2_v0.1.1\ContactHands\contact_hands_two_stream\engine\custom_predictor.py", line 43, in __call__
    predictions = self.model([inputs])
  File "C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\detectron2_v0.1.1\ContactHands\contact_hands_two_stream\modeling\meta_arch\second_stream_rcnn.py", line 52, in forward
    return self.inference(batched_inputs)
  File "C:\detectron2_v0.1.1\ContactHands\contact_hands_two_stream\modeling\meta_arch\second_stream_rcnn.py", line 112, in inference
    second_stream_outputs = self.roi_heads(images, features, proposals, None)
  File "C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\detectron2_v0.1.1\ContactHands\contact_hands_two_stream\modeling\roi_heads\second_stream_roi_head.py", line 123, in forward
    pred_instances = self._forward_box(features, proposals)
  File "C:\detectron2_v0.1.1\ContactHands\contact_hands_two_stream\modeling\roi_heads\second_stream_roi_head.py", line 176, in _forward_box
    box_features = self.box_pooler(features, [x.proposal_boxes for x in proposals])
  File "C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2\modeling\poolers.py", line 233, in forward
    output[inds] = pooler(x_level, pooler_fmt_boxes_level)
  File "C:\Users\berge\.conda\envs\detectron2_v0.1.1\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1130, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2\layers\roi_align.py", line 95, in forward
    input, rois, self.output_size, self.spatial_scale, self.sampling_ratio, self.aligned
  File "c:\detectron2_v0.1.1\detectron2\layers\roi_align.py", line 20, in forward
    input, roi, spatial_scale, output_size[0], output_size[1], sampling_ratio, aligned
RuntimeError: Not compiled with GPU support
```

Please help!